# Plotting (multilevel) multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-visualization, multilevel-analysis, ggplot2

Lets say I have some data like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)

groups <- floor(runif(1000, min=1, max=7))
sex <- rep(c("Male", "Female"), times= 500)
value1 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=10)
value2 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=100)
value3 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=200)
response <- runif(1000, min=1, max=100)

df <- data.frame(groups, sex, response, value1, value2, value3)
```

And I run the following mixed-effects model:

```
model <- lmer(scale(response) ~ scale(value1) + scale(value2) + scale(value3) + factor(sex) + (1|groups), data=df)
summary(model)
```

To get the following output for the fixed effects:

```
Fixed effects:
  Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)       0.01659    0.04479 995.00000   0.370    0.711
scale(value1)    -0.01159    0.03168 995.00000  -0.366    0.715
scale(value2)    -0.02538    0.03172 995.00000  -0.800    0.424
scale(value3)    -0.03454    0.03171 995.00000  -1.089    0.276
factor(sex)Male  -0.03317    0.06340 995.00000  -0.523    0.601
```

Now, I'm interested in visualizing the relationship between `value1` and `response` so I thought about using the slope and intercept from the model summary to create a plot like this:

```
ggplot(aes(x = scale(value1), y = scale(response)), data=df) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0.01659, slope = -0.01159)
```

The problem with this approach is that the scatterplot points are showing the raw relationship between the 2 variables, whereas the slope and intercept values (abline) is showing the relationship after controlling for all of the other variables

Whats the correct/typical way to visualize the relationship between a predictor and response in multiple regression (using ggplot)? I'd like to be able to show the magnitude of the relationship after controlling for all the other variables in my model

Additionally, I'm also unsure how the presence of a factor and a random effects variable affects the creation of these plots

Is there where avplots (or termplots?) come in? I can create avplots easily enough for regular fixed effects models, but it doesnt seem to work in the case of mixed effects models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of packages that support the plotting of marginal effects of fixed effects in a mixed model. I'm aware of the following: `visreg`, `effects`, `ggeffects` and `sjPlot`. In what follows below, I illustrate the usage of `visreg` and `ggeffects`.

### Using `visreg`

The [`visreg`](https://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/mixed.html) package supports plotting fixed effects as well as random effects.

An example using the data in the question would be:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(visreg)

set.seed(142857)
groups <- floor(runif(1000, min=1, max=7))
sex <- rep(c("Male", "Female"), times= 500)
value1 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=10)
value2 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=100)
value3 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=200)
response <- runif(1000, min=1, max=100)

df <- data.frame(groups, sex, response, value1, value2, value3)

model <- lmer(scale(response) ~ scale(value1) + scale(value2) + scale(value3) + factor(sex) + (1|groups), data=df)

visreg(model
       , "value1" # Variable to plot
       , cond = list(value2 = 0, value3 = 0, sex = "Female") # Values of the other variables in the model
       , gg = TRUE # Use ggplot2 for plotting?
)
```

[image: Fixed effects plot]

The points display the partial residuals. If you set the option `gg` to `TRUE`, `ggplot2` is used for plotting and base R otherwise.

By default, the values of the other variables in the model are set at their median or mode for continuous and categorical variables, respectively. Using the argument `cond`, you can set the values of the variables at arbitrary values.

### Using `ggeffects`

The package [`ggeffects`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/randomeffects.html) is also able to plot marginal effects. It is able to include the variances of the random effects into account (but this doesn't work here with these artificial data).

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)

set.seed(142857)
groups <- floor(runif(1000, min=1, max=7))
sex <- rep(c("Male", "Female"), times= 500)
value1 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=10)
value2 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=100)
value3 <- runif(1000, min=1, max=200)
response <- runif(1000, min=1, max=100)

df <- data.frame(groups, sex, response, value1, value2, value3)

model <- lmer(scale(response) ~ scale(value1) + scale(value2) + scale(value3) + factor(sex) + (1|groups), data=df)

pr <- ggpredict(model, "value1")

plot(pr)
```

[image: ggeffects plot]